# Work out a cron job schedule

Tags: linux, cron

I have a set of 6 jobs to be run via cron. Let's call them jobs A,B,C,D,E & F
'A' & 'B' take 2 mins to complete, 'C' , 'D' , 'E' & 'F' take 3 min each to complete. No job is dependent on the other

The problem of running them all together is a burst of CPU & then everything is idle. I'm looking to space the execution of these jobs apart such that the jobs don't lock up the resources & produce erroneous results which is to say I would like to not have these jobs overlap with any other

I'm finding it quite hard to work out the schedule to run these.

Comment: Why not just write script ''Z'' that calls all the others consecutively?

Comment: I use `run-parts dir` where dit hold all you scripts. you can add sleeping script between them to allow for CPU/load average  to cool down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user Archemar already pointed out in his comment use the utility `run-parts`.

In many Linux distributions this is also used to execute all the cron scripts of
severaly system software packages stored in the directories `/etc/cron.daily`, `/etc/cron.hourly` and so on. Normally `run-parts` will execute all your scripts one after the other in sequence.  Beware of the naming conventions: `run-parts` will normally not execute any script files which contain a period in the filename.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pefu. I totally forgot about this until I bumped on my own question now for the same problem. lol